# How to properly close a JMS connection?

Tags: java, jms, spring-jms

I am trying to use Spring's SingleConnectionFactory, where there are 2 connection factories, and only one of them should be able to connect at a time.

```
<bean id="connectionFactory1" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory102">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
        <bean class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">
            <property name="username" value="LOGIN" />
            <property name="password" value="PASS" />
            <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
                <bean class="com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsQueueConnectionFactory">
                    <constructor-arg value="URL" />
                    <constructor-arg value="CLIENT_ID" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="reconnectOnException" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="connectionFactory2" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory102">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
        <bean class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">
            <property name="username" value="LOGIN" />
            <property name="password" value="PASS" />
            <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
                <bean class="com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsQueueConnectionFactory">
                    <constructor-arg value="URL" />
                    <constructor-arg value="CLIENT_ID" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="reconnectOnException" value="true" />
</bean>
```

By using the same client id in both factories(CLIENT_ID), I made sure that when I create connection from one factory, I can't create another connection from the other factory (throws InvalidClientIDException, so this is as expected). But the issue is, when I close the connection I got from first factory, and try to get connection from second factory, I'm still getting the exception.

Using the following Java code:

```
Connection connection1 = connectionFactory1.createConnection();
connection1.close();

Connection connection2 = connectionFactory2.createConnection();
```

What is the proper way of closing first connection, so that it allows me to create connection using the second factory?

Also, note that I am not using Queues here. I have to achieve this without queues.

Comment: What is the logic that detect that you got the first connection opened to throw the error?

Comment: `factory.resetConnection()`

Comment: @MinhKieu, I am using the same CLIENT_ID in both factories, so trying to create another connection from a different factory will cause an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `factory.resetConnection()` to actually close the single connection.

Comment: Where do you have that method resetConnection()? I checked, there is no such a method in SingleConnectionFactory102.

Comment: What version of Spring are you using? That factory doesn't exist after 3.2. At least in 3.2, `resetConnection()` is on the [super class SingleConnectionFactory](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/3.2.x/spring-jms/src/main/java/org/springframework/jms/connection/SingleConnectionFactory.java#L319). If there is no `resetConnection()` in your version, try `destroy()`.

Comment: My spring version is 2.5. I can try with later version.

Comment: `resetConnection()` exists in 2.5 [see the javadocs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/jms/connection/SingleConnectionFactory.html).

Comment: Right, it's available in version 2.5. I checked, it resolved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend the accepted answer. Let me address this and several points raised by other answers to this question.

A better approach would look something like this example (JavaEE6 JMS style) which sends an ObjectMessage to a Queue from within a stateless EJB:

```
@Stateless
public class SendEventsBean {

  private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SendEventsBean.class);

  @Resource(mappedName = "jms/MyConnectionFactory")
  private ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory;

  @Resource(mappedName = "jms/myApp/MyQueue"
  private Queue queue;

  public void sendEvent() {
    Connection jmsConnection = null;
    try {
        connection = jmsConnectionFactory.createConnection();
        Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
        MyObj obj = new MyObj(1, "Foo");
        ObjectMessage myObjMsg = session.createObjectMessage(obj);
        producer.send(myObjMsg);
    } catch (JMSException jmxEx) {
        log.error("Couldn't send JMS message: ", jmsEx);
    }finally{
        if (jmsConnection != null) {
            try {
                jmsConnection.close();
            }catch(JMSException ex) {
               log.warn("Couldn't close JMSConnection: ", ex);
            }
        }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: But, I need it without involving Queues. It is just not feasible for me to request creation of a new EMS queue in my company infrastructure for this purpose.